# windows 2012 server VPN routing

Tags: networking, vpn, windows-server-2012, routing-table

Got stuck a bit.

I have a windows 2012 server (S0) on a static IP address.

Laptop (L1) is connecting and receiving ... .10 ip. 
Tablet (T1) is connecting and receiving ... .11 ip (ip class of choice).

Both L1 and T1 connect using mobile data connection. Once PPTP Vpn established to S0 I can ping .11 from .10 and viceversa.

T1 has an USB to ethernet adapter connecting via cable to 192.168.124.1 (a device which always has this static IP). The usb to eth on T1 is set to 192.168.124.100.

I need to be able to connect from L1 to 192.168.124.1 - do I need to implement static routes on L1 to point to connection on T1 and routes on server? Am a bit stuck, as I don't want to provide internet access via windows 2012 server, rather keep it a closed network.

thanks

Comment: How is 192.168.124.1 connected to the server?

Answer (score 0):

192.168.124.1 is connected via ethernet cable to T1 usb to eth dongle.
T1(tablet w10) dials pptp into server.

Was thinking of adding T1 to the domain.

Otherwise, it is not connected or not seen. Was considering creating static routes on S0, L1, T1.